# FIlter array of rectangles so that there are no collisions

Tags: javascript, algorithm, collision-detection

I have an array of rectangles that might collide with each other. I want to filter out the collided ones with minimal reduction. What's an optimal way of doing this?

Here is some code for context:

```
type Rect = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  width: number;
  height: number;
};

function isRectsColliding(rect1: Rect, rect2: Rect) {
  return !(
    rect1.x > rect2.x + rect2.width ||
    rect1.x + rect1.width < rect2.x ||
    rect1.y > rect2.y + rect2.height ||
    rect1.y + rect1.height < rect2.y
  );
}

const rects = [
  { x: 0, y: 181, width: 6, height: 6 },
  { x: 6, y: 147, width: 6, height: 6 },
  { x: 32, y: 124, width: 6, height: 6 },
  { x: 34, y: 7, width: 6, height: 6 },
  { x: 35, y: 11, width: 6, height: 6 },
  { x: 36, y: 0, width: 6, height: 6 },
  { x: 39, y: 15, width: 6, height: 6 },
];

const filteredRectIndexes = rects.reduce(?).map((_, idx) => idx); // should be [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```

Thanks.

Comment: If rectangle **A** collides with rectangle **B**. Do you want to keep **A** and remove **B** or do you want to remove them both ?

Comment: You want to find the largest set of rectangles without any collisions? That's not a trivial task and I doubt that's gonna be possible with a single `reduce` The straight forward way (not necessarily the fastest) is to generate all possible subsets of your set of rectangles and eliminate those subsets where you find a collision. From the remaining sets, take the biggest one ...

Comment: @Titus the first one, I want to keep A.

Comment: @derpirscher it is not homework. It is about a zoomable chart in which I show scatters. When zoomed out I don't want to display collided scatter points. It doesn't have to be a single reduce function, of course. I need an optimized algorithm for the task since the chart is displayed on mobile. I didn't request the final code; rather seeking the algorithm fitted for this specific requirement.

Comment: In that case, you can do something like this: `rects.reduce((a, c) => ((a.length && a.some((r) => isRectsColliding(r, c))) ? a : [...a, c]), []).map((r) => rects.indexOf(r))`. I've modified the `.map(..)` callback because in your case, it doesn't make any sense. That callback will never skip numbers.

Comment: This is the [vertex cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) problem which is NP-hard. But you can start by building the graph. Doing that efficiently is a problem on its own... so solve that one first.

Comment: @derpirscher The OP's response to my question (*the first one, I want to keep A*) led me to believe that this is the expected result.

Comment: @Titus OP also states in the question "*with minimal reduction*" ... I interpet OPs answer to your comment as "*don't remove both, but keep one of them*" (because the third option would be to remove **A** or **B**, depending on which allows to keep more rectangles)

Comment: @derpirscher is right. Preferably, I would want to retain the maximum number of possible rectangles that don't collide with each other.

Comment: As @trincot notes, this problem is NP-hard (though since it is a special case rather than a generalization of a canonical NP-hard problem (independent set, not vertex cover), this fact is far from obvious; in 1D, there would be an O(n log n)-time algorithm). Are the "rectangles" always going to be squares of the same width?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat yes they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a reduce function that you can use to get the result that you've mentioned:

```js
function isRectsColliding(rect1, rect2) {
  return !(
    rect1.x > rect2.x + rect2.width ||
    rect1.x + rect1.width < rect2.x ||
    rect1.y > rect2.y + rect2.height ||
    rect1.y + rect1.height < rect2.y
  );
}

const rects = [{
    x: 0,
    y: 181,
    width: 6,
    height: 6
  },
  {
    x: 6,
    y: 147,
    width: 6,
    height: 6
  },
  {
    x: 32,
    y: 124,
    width: 6,
    height: 6
  },
  {
    x: 34,
    y: 7,
    width: 6,
    height: 6
  },
  {
    x: 35,
    y: 11,
    width: 6,
    height: 6
  },
  {
    x: 36,
    y: 0,
    width: 6,
    height: 6
  },
  {
    x: 39,
    y: 15,
    width: 6,
    height: 6
  },
];

const filteredRectIndexes = rects.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (a.length && a.some((r) => isRectsColliding(r, c))) {
      return a;
    }
    return [...a, c];
  }, [])
  .map((r) => rects.indexOf(r)); // should be [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6]

console.log(filteredRectIndexes);
```

I've modified the callback passes to `.map(..)` because `.map((_, idx) => idx)` will always return an empty array or an array of consecutive numbers.

Like @derpirscher mentioned, this will not give you the biggest set of non-colliding rectangles because it processes rectangles in the order that they are in the original array (current rectangle does not collide with any of the previous rectangles).

Keeping the maximum number of non-colliding rectangles can get quite complex, a simple way of doing it will be to first sort the original array of rectangles by the number of collisions each of them has, here is an example:

```js
function isRectsColliding(rect1, rect2) {
  return !(
    rect1.x > rect2.x + rect2.width ||
    rect1.x + rect1.width < rect2.x ||
    rect1.y > rect2.y + rect2.height ||
    rect1.y + rect1.height < rect2.y
  );
}

const rects = [{
    x: 0,
    y: 181,
    width: 6,
    height: 6
  },
  {
    x: 6,
    y: 147,
    width: 6,
    height: 6
  },
  {
    x: 32,
    y: 124,
    width: 6,
    height: 6
  },
  {
    x: 34,
    y: 7,
    width: 6,
    height: 6
  },
  {
    x: 35,
    y: 11,
    width: 6,
    height: 6
  },
  {
    x: 36,
    y: 0,
    width: 6,
    height: 6
  },
  {
    x: 39,
    y: 15,
    width: 6,
    height: 6
  },
];

const rectsWithCount = rects.map((c, _, arr) => {
  const count = arr.filter((r) => r !== c && isRectsColliding(r, c)).length;
  return { ...c, count };
});

rectsWithCount.sort((a, b) => a.count - b.count);

const filteredRectIndexes = rectsWithCount.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (a.length && a.some((r) => isRectsColliding(r, c))) {
      return a;
    }
    return [...a, c];
  }, [])
  .map((r) => rects.findIndex((rect) => r.x === rect.x && r.y === rect.y && r.width === rect.width && r.height === rect.height));

console.log(filteredRectIndexes);
```

Comment: This will for sure return *some* subset of not colliding rectangles. But depending in which order they appear in the original array, it may or may not return the maximum set ...

Comment: For instance if the list consists of rectangles `A, B, C, D` and `A` collides with each of the others, but none of `B, C, D` collide with each other, your approach would only return `A`, but the exepected answer (at least on my understanding of the question, i might be wrong) would be `B, C, D`

Comment: @derpirscher Yes, I get that. I've added an explanation to my answer to specify what my approach is actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your declaration that the rectangles are squares of the same width, after scaling this width to 1, this problem is maximum independent set in the intersection graph of unit squares. Unfortunately, Dániel Marx ("Parameterized Complexity of Independence and Domination on Geometric Graphs", 2006) showed that it's W[1]-hard, which means that we don't have a guaranteed fast and high-quality approximation, let alone an exact algorithm.

Practically speaking, if I absolutely needed the optimal solution, I would compute the graph (bucket squares by (floor(x / width), floor(y / width)), check each 2x2 bucket block for overlaps) and hand off the resulting maximum independent set problem to a mixed integer program (MIP) solver. For a user interface, however, this seems like a bad idea, since the MIP solver will take an unpredictable and possibly large amount of time to find an optimal solution.

Instead, I would focus on maximal independent sets. A maxim*al* independent set may not include as many squares as the maxim*um* independent set, but you can't add a square without creating an overlap, so IMO it should look OK. Titus's answer will give you a maximal independent set.

For scalability and consistent zooming, I would also suggest that you compute consistent maximal independent sets for all possible zooms offline. The zoom needed for two squares to overlap is a monotone function of the Manhattan (L1) distance between their centers. If you can afford quadratic time for preprocessing, select the two furthest squares first, then repeatedly select the next square with the maximum minimum distance to a square already selected. Show a prefix of this list depending on the zoom. You can figure out where the prefix ends by doing binary search (record the minimum distances during preprocessing). If quadratic is too much, there are faster but more complicated algorithms to the same end; see [farthest-first traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farthest-first_traversal).